# Eclipse plugin and editor

Tags: java, eclipse, file, plugins, editor

How to open a file outside of the  project programically in a new editor window ? I've been searching all over the internet and nothing seems to work. 
I have  eclipse 4.4.
I thought something so simple as opening a file will be easy but somehow it keeps me awake at night.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment as yet, so adding my question/suggestion as an answer.

What do you mean by your question? You mean something like a command to open a target file in some editor that is installed on your computer.

You could try using

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime ().exec ("<path to editor>/some_editor.exe");
```

If the program allows taking file to open as parameter, you could place that too in commmand above towards the end.

I hope this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

To open an editor on a file which is not in the current workspace use:

```
String path = ... path to file

IFileStore fileStore = EFS.getLocalFileSystem().getStore(new Path(path));

IWorkbenchPage page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();

IDE.openInternalEditorOnFileStore(page, fileStore);
```

Note: some editors may not support files that are not in the workspace.